# using ready() and change() interferres somehow

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I am trying to get following jsfiddle to work: http://jsfiddle.net/hLbnfx2n/7/
But I am having difficulties using ready() and change() simultanely, so that
some bugs happen (if you click "Ja", then "Nein", followed by "Ja" for the first
question, the

```
    $('#radioListId2 input').first().attr('checked',true);
    $('#radioListId3 input').first().attr('checked',true);
```

doesnt work as intended.

What I want is, that the button is only active when 4 answers are given, and that when the first answer is "Ja", the following questions 2 and 3 are answerded (as "Ja") and deactivated automatically.

The different Tasks seem to work, but they do not acting together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't with `ready()` and `change()`, it's with `click()` and `change()`. The problem is that your `change` handler fires before `click`, which you can see by logging events when received on your buttons and document:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='C002$ctl00$ctl00$C011$ctl00$ctl00$radioButtons_radiobuttons']").on("click", function () {
        console.log('input received click');
    });
});

$(document).on('change click', function(ev) {
    console.log('document received event: ', ev.type);
});
```

As you click a button, the log shows:

```
document received event:  change
input received click
document received event:  click
```

There are several ways you could accomplish what you're after. Here's one: use a single `change()` handler to inspect the value of all of your buttons and set the form state appropriately based on the value of the other radio buttons and subsequently, the total number of radio buttons checked.

Comment: I am not quite sure to understand it right, because the "click"-event for the button isnt happening til everything is filled out (?) I am not the JS-pro, just a beginner :/

Comment: The issue is that you take an atomic action (you want the values updated, and the UI updated, in response to the same user action) and split it between two different events: `click` and `change`. As far as I know, there isn't a specification about which event will be handled first, which means you're going to be at the mercy of the browser implementation. Sticking with a single handler ensures your response action happens all at once. Putting the handler in `change` ensures the value is updated by the time the event fires.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to handle it, which can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/hLbnfx2n/13/
I used the click-event to trigger the change-event by force with:

```
$("#sai").click(function () {
     $("input").trigger('change');
});
```

to get rid of the problem. I am sure it is not the best way to do so, but it fits my needs for the meantime.